# Meteor: wait until file is generated

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, future

I do a Meteor.call() synchronously (without callbacks), which downloads from a location and generates a file on the server successfully, and then Meteor.Router.to('/file/generated.just.now');

However, sometimes the file takes a few extra seconds to generate and I redirect to the file before it exists.

I've tried to use Futures and Fibers, but not sure if this can achieve blocking (wait until file is finished written);

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  var request = Npm.require('request');
  var fs = Npm.require('fs');
  var Future = Npm.require('fibers/future'), wait = Future.wait;
  Fiber = Npm.require('fibers');

var result = function(){
            downloadAndSaveFile(content.pdf, filename).wait();
          }.future();

 function downloadAndSaveFile(fileUrl, fileName) {
    var future = new Future;
    request(fileUrl).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(getPath() + fileName)).on('closed', function(){
      future.return();
    });
    return future;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meteor's router `.to` function is client side only, used to invoke the routing callbacks. It doesn't tell the browser to physically redirect, only swap out the DOM to reflect the new page according to what the templates & your routes are.

If you want to redirect you should use

```
window.location = 'newurl';
```

Or a link that the user click's created from the `.call` callback.

Comment: the problem lies in that redirection happens too early I'm wondering if there's a way to wait until that file is fully available before redirecting there. whether I use Router or window.location is irrelevant.

Comment: If .to works for you then I guess thats ok, you should follow the paradigm for futures set out at : https://gist.github.com/possibilities/3443021. I think your returning  data to the call before the file is ready. You've also not placed your code for the call up? Do you directly wait for the code to execute on runtime?